# How to clear cache from an iframe?

Tags: java, php

I am interrogated a platform with another platform in an `iframe`. But problem is that i logout from the parent window then the `iframe` take chache.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" 
        id="chat_container" 
        src="<?php echo $this->meetingUrl; ?>" 
        allow="camera; microphone">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

You can add the randomly string end of your iframe url.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" 
    id="chat_container" 
    src="<?php echo $this->meetingUrl; ?>?v=xkjsdkjhasdk" 
    allow="camera; microphone">
</iframe>
```

Solution 2:

Please try to add the html meta tag on your head of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```